# solr proximity search with NOT

Tags: apache, solr, proximity

For proximity search in SOLR, I am forming query like "word1 word2"~10. This is returning the documents which are containing word1 and word2 are with in 10 words distance.

Now i want reverse of this search , i.e I want to get the documents which are not containing word1 and word2 are with in 10 words distance.

To get this I made query like  NOT "word1 word2"~10.

But it is not returning any documents. Please advice.

Comment: So you need those results that do contain these two words, just not within a distance of 10?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with the following negative query:

```
+word1 +word2 -"word1 word2"~10
```

You are effectively searching all documents that contain both "word1" and "word2", excluding those that are within a span distance of 10.